# add method of linked list java

Tags: java, linked-list

When adding a node to a linked list I guess the idea would be as follows:

```
Declare newNode 
Add to the front if front == null
else if there is already a node in the list
```

However this does not seem to work

```
public boolean add (E e) {

  ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>(e,null);

  if (front == null){
      front = newNode;
      rear = newNode;
      objectCount++;
      return true;
  }

      front.next = newNode;
      rear.next = newNode;
      rear = newNode;
      objectCount++;
      return true;
}
```

but when I run this for the list "a","b","c","d","e" it doesn't return a list size of 5 but of size 2. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the new node next to your front and your rear nodes. In order to solve the problem, you should just add it to the rear node (assuming your list will only accept new values in the rear).

```
//front.next = newNode;
rear.next = newNode;
rear = newNode;
objectCount++;
return true;
```

Comment: It worked great and I understand how you did it and what my mistake was.Good answer.

Comment: @nitiger you're welcome :). Please don't forget to mark the post as an answer after 15 mins you have posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify the next pointer inside the front node. If a front node exists, follow this steps:

1. Create a new node
2. Set rear's next node to the new node.
3. Set rear node to new node.
4. Increment the counter.